# Gravity on other planets

Tags: newtonian-gravity, soft-question, terminology

Why we use the word"Earth' pull" while  defining gravity when gravity also exist on other planets of solar system?

Comment: "We" don't use the word "Earth pull" (is that even a word?) when defining gravity.

Comment: Traditionally the word 'gravity' meant the force between the earth and other masses, while 'gravitation' is the more general term (i.e. between any two masses). Although very few care for this distinction.

Comment: I have never seen the term "Earth's pull".  Where is it used?

Comment: I had read in my text book about it there was mentioned that it's earth pull and i read about gravity on other planets So, i asked about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's incorrect definition propagated by text books for simplicity sake. Gravity should always be defined as

> a force that attracts a body towards another physical body with mass.

For simplicity sake, gravity is taught as the force with which Earth pulls a body.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an answer which I think supplements some of the other comments. @lemon notes that "gravity" refers to the pull towards the Earth while "gravitation" is more general, but notes that this is archaic. In fact, it is a very old term and the history is interesting, so take this as a "history of science" type answer. Disclaimer that all of what I present here is old philosophy and should not be taken as physical.

In Aristotelian physics, the natural state of an object is a type of motion inherent in the object. (Compare: in Newtonian physics, the natural state of an object is to remain moving in a straight line.) In the five-element system he proposed, air and fire had the tendency to move upwards, away from the center of the universe (i.e., the center of the Earth) while earth and water had the tendency to move downwards. He called these tendencies "levity" and "gravity," and then ascribed the motion of the stars to "quintessence," a fifth element which had a natural circular motion. This was meant to account for the observation that motion on Earth seems to always come to a halt, while the motion of the stars seemed fixed and unchanging.

So if at times there seem to be places where "gravity" is relegated to Earth, this may be a linguistic holdover from the time when gravity was not seen as a physical "force" (because that concept was not well-defined) but rather as the observed tendency of objects to fall.